# want to connect t divs with each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to connect two tabs with their content considering that I can toggle between them. I tried with onclick().But It is easy If I have two or three tabs. But if I use multiple tab what will be the best approach to solve it ?I also want know why I can't use forEach method here.

```js
    let tabs=document.getElementById("tabs");
    let tabList=tabs.getElementsByTagName("div");
    let cont=document.getElementById("tab-content");
    let contList=cont.getElementsByTagName("div");
    
    for(var i=0; i<tabList.length; i++){
        tabList[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
            
            
            for(var j=0; j<contList.length; j++){
                
                if(i==j){
                    contList[j].classList.add("active");
                    
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

```css
 .tab1{
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
 .tab2{
    background-color: crimson;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.content1{
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
}
.content2{
    display: none;
    background-color: crimson;

}

.active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="tabs">
            <div class="tab1">
                Page 1
                
            </div>
            <div class="tab2">
                Page 2
            </div>
    
        </div>
        <div id="tab-content">
            <div class="content1 active">
                <h1>Page 1 content</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content2">
                <h1>Page 2 content</h1>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="p.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `anchor` in combination with `:target` might be the best solution for this as it requires no JS to do this.